# Heroku: Enabling MTLS on postgres... failed! Not Found

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to enable mutual MTLS on my PostgreSQL database, however  whenever I run the command `heroku data:mtls:create DATABASE_NAME --app APP_NAME` (With my own DATABASE_NAME and APP_NAME obviously) I get the error `Enabling MTLS on DATABASE_NAME... failed! Not Found.` I am not sure why I am getting this error because I installed the MTLS plugin just fine from the same command line, I am logged in to heroku and when I run `heroku apps` my APP_NAME comes up just fine. If anybody could help me out with this that would be amazing!